# How to add other primitives inside custom component: rotating playing card

Tags: components, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

I want to create a card, once clicked on, it rotates 180°.

So I want to create a card component, that has a plane for the back side and a plane for the front side.
Once clicked on the card-entity, it rotates both planes, so that is looks like the card is turning around.

So here's what I got so far:

custom component: Card, gets added X-times. 
A cursor detects a mouseEnter, then I want to card to rotate.
On mouseLeave, the card rotates back to the original state.

So, how can I achieve this the best?
Multiple meshes in a custom component or something?

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('card', {
schema: {
    material: {type:'selector'},
    hoverMaterial: {type: 'selector'},
    card: {type: 'selector'}
},
multiple: true,
element: null,
init: function () {
    console.log("Card loaded");
    var data = this.data;
    this.el.setAttribute('material', 'src', data.material);
    this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.onMouseEnter.bind(this));
    this.el.addEventListener('mouseleave', this.onMouseLeave.bind(this));
},

onMouseEnter: function() {
        this.el.removeEventListener('mouseenter', this.onMouseEnter.bind(this));
        this.el.setAttribute('material', 'src', this.data.hoverMaterial);
        this.el.setAttribute('rotation', '0 180 0');

},

onMouseLeave: function () {
    //this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.onMouseEnter.bind(this));
    this.el.setAttribute('material', 'src', this.data.material);
    this.el.setAttribute('rotation', '0 0 0');

},

update: function (oldData) {

},

remove: function () {
    this.el.removeObject3D('mesh');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom component that appends two child entities to itself with the appropriate orientations and materials - for front and back sides.

You could also add a transparent plane mesh to the component, to enable raycasting.

Reference to the HTML node is `this.el` and you can manipulate it like a regular HTML node.

Code sample:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('card', {
  // ...
  addChildren: function () {
     this.frontFace = document.createElement('a-entity');
     this.backFace = document.createElement('a-entity');
     // ...
     this.el.appendChild(this.frontFace);
     this.el.appendChild(this.backFace);
  }
  // ...
```

For the input use either a [`cursor`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/cursor.html#sidebar) component or the [`raycaster`](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/raycaster.html#sidebar) component itself. Note that you have to have a mesh on the component you are trying to use in raycasting.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Do you know how to add a child to itself and not in the main scene...?

Comment: In the component use the following method: `this.el.appendChild(<node>)`

Comment: Thank you Nikolay, I'll try this ASAP!